# Can't breakOut for a custom Iterator

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Looking at other SO answers about `ResultSet` I created an `Iterator` for it:

```
class RsIterator(rs: ResultSet) extends Iterator[ResultSet] {
  override def hasNext = rs.next
  override def next() = rs
}
```

Then I'm using it to create a list:

```
def selectOneCol[T](q: String, params: Any*): Seq[T] = selectInner(q, params: _*) { rs =>
  for (rsRow <- new RsIterator(rs)) yield rsRow.getObject(1).asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

And what IDEA tells me is "Expression of type `Iterator[T]` doesn't conform to expected type `_T`" and I'm guessing it's because I'm expected to return a `Seq` but return an `Iterator` instead. I understand Scala yields an `Iterator` because it's where the elements initially come from, but why isn't this working? --

```
(for (rsRow <- new RsIterator(rs)) yield rsRow.getObject(1).asInstanceOf[T])(collection.breakOut)
```

The error is "Application does not take parameters" for the breakOut call. Does this mean Scala doesn't "know" how to convert an `Iterator` into a `Seq`, or should my custom `Iterator` implement some special interfaces to make it work?

P.S. I know `Iterator.toSeq` works, just interested to know why the `breakOut` ... breaks.

Thanks.